# How to persist authentication in firebase for > 1h?

Tags: ios, firebase, web-applications, local-storage, firebase-authentication

I'm using `firebase.auth()` for my Website. I activated the `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` option to stay logged in (which shouldn't be necessary, since its the default in web, according to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence, but it doesn't matter, if the option is explicitly set or not).

The expected behaviour is, that the user stays logged in, until he actively signs out, no matter if the browser was closed. etc...

In my case, the user is logged out after an hour or so (didn't tracked it exactly). This happens on safari, or if I add it to the homescreen as webapp. I this the intended behaviour, or am I doing something wrong?

## Update: Problem solved

I totally missed a 403 answer in the console after a few couple of minute:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Token Service API has not been used in project xxxxxx before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/securetoken.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxxx then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console API activation",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/securetoken.googleapis.com/overview?project=xxxxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I went to the url, activated the token api and voila: persistent Logins :)

Afterwards I looked up the official docs, seeing if I missed this step somewhere, but I can't find any hints on that api activation.

Comment: The user should remain logged in. The Auth state is persisted in localStorage. Are you checking `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to determine if a user is logged in?

Comment: Problem solved, see updated question.